# Next js and Next Auth overlapping react declarations

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am running Next js and Next Auth in multiple project, and all of a sudden all of them decided to crash with the same error.

```
Module parse failed: Identifier '_react' has already been declared (14:6)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const _material = require("@mui/material");
| const _xDataGrid = require("@mui/x-data-grid");
> const _react = require("next-auth/react");
| const _reportTable = /*#__PURE__*/
```

a simple example that crashes looks like this...
As you can see from the example below. I am not importing react twice.

```
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowsProp } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

import ReportTable from "../src/components/ReportTable";

export default function Home() {
  const findSession = () => {
    const session = getSession();

    console.log(session);
    return session;
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <ReportTable title="Price Books">
        <DataGrid
          sx={{ border: "0" }}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          headerHeight={40}
        />
      </ReportTable>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

If I remove the getSession import at the top everything runs fine. The other developers on my team can run these project just fine, so I believe it's an environmental issue on my side.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

I have built the project and it works fine. The errors only occur in my dev environment.
I also cloned the repo on my personal machine and it worked fine there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a new plugin that came out today, "Code Ninja". If you are facing this issue, disable that VSCode extension.